operator classes are only allowed for the last column of an inverted index
Since I migrated my Django application from MariaDb to CockraochDB which is basically Postgres Syntax I get the following error, I really do not understand, I also do not find any referenced on the web or where I can start to debug this.
At my Django Application, I first do manage.py make migrations, to generate the migrations files, after that I do manage.py migrate to apply these against my CockroachDB and this happens:
Running migrations:
Applying App_CDN.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django_prometheus/db/common.py", line 69, in execute
return super().execute(*args, **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: operator classes are only allowed for the last column of an inverted index


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 356, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration
with self.connection.schema_editor(
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 167, in __exit__
self.execute(sql)
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 48, in execute
return super().execute(sql, None)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 202, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django_prometheus/db/common.py", line 69, in execute
return super().execute(*args, **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator classes are only allowed for the last column of an inverted index

models.py
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class LiberaBackend(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    resource_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Resource Name", blank=False, null=False, max_length=50, unique=True)
    access_key = models.CharField(verbose_name="Access Key", blank=False, max_length=128)
    secret_key = models.CharField(verbose_name="Secret Key", blank=False, max_length=128)
    psk_api_binhex = models.CharField(verbose_name="PSK API Binhex", blank=False, max_length=128)
    psk_admin_binhex = models.CharField(verbose_name="PSK Admin Binhex", blank=False, max_length=128)
    bucket = models.CharField(verbose_name="Media Bucket", blank=False, null=False, max_length=128)
    klx_bucket = models.CharField(verbose_name="KLX Bucket", blank=False, null=False, max_length=128)
    resource_bucket = models.CharField(verbose_name="Resource Bucket", blank=False, null=False, max_length=128)
    endpoint = models.CharField(verbose_name="Endpoint", blank=False, null=False, max_length=128)
    region = models.CharField(verbose_name="Region", blank=False, null=False, max_length=128)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    def stream_endpoint(self) -> str:
        stream_endpoint = str(self.endpoint + "/" + "stream")
        return stream_endpoint

    def tld(self) -> str:
        tld = str(self.endpoint.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", ""))
        return tld

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Libera Backend"
        verbose_name_plural = "Libera Backends"


class LiberaServerIPv4(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ipv4_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name="IPv4 Address", blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)


class LiberaServerIPv6(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ipv6_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv6', verbose_name="IPv6 Address", blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)


# Lazy Model
class LiberaServerIPv4Relation(models.Model):
    libera_server = models.ForeignKey('LiberaServer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ipv4_address = models.ForeignKey(LiberaServerIPv4, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)


# Lazy Model
class LiberaServerIPv6Relation(models.Model):
    libera_server = models.ForeignKey('LiberaServer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ipv6_address = models.ForeignKey(LiberaServerIPv6, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)


class LiberaServer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ipv4_addresses = models.ManyToManyField(LiberaServerIPv4, related_name='libera_server_ipv4_relation', through=LiberaServerIPv4Relation)
    ipv6_addresses = models.ManyToManyField(LiberaServerIPv6, related_name='libera_server_ipv6_relation', through=LiberaServerIPv6Relation)
    hostname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Hostname", blank=False, null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    country_code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country Code", blank=False, null=False, max_length=8)
    libera_backend = models.ForeignKey(LiberaBackend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='libera_backend_relation')
    last_successful_contact = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)


class LiberaServerMetric(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    libera_server = models.ForeignKey(LiberaServer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='libera_server_relation')
    uptime_seconds = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Uptime", blank=False)
    load_average_percentage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Load Average Percentage", blank=False)
    memory_usage_percentage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Memory Usage", blank=False)
    client_connections = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Client Connections", blank=False, null=False)
    gateway_connections = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Gateway Connections", blank=False)
    bandwidth_utilization_mbits = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Bandwidth Utilization Mbit/s", blank=False, null=False)
    bandwidth_available_mbits = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Bandwidth Available Mbit/s", blank=False, null=False)
    bandwidth_utilization_percentage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Bandwidth Utilization Percentage", blank=False, null=False)
    total_disk_size_bytes = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Total Disk Size Bytes", blank=False, null=False)
    free_disk_size_bytes = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Free Disk Size Bytes", blank=False, null=False)
    cache_disk_usage_bytes = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Cache Disk Usage Bytes", blank=False, null=False)
    cache_object_count = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name="Cache Object Count", blank=False, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

0001_initial.py:
# Generated by Django 5.0.6 on 2024-06-28 13:02

import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone
import uuid
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaBackend',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('resource_name', models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Resource Name')),
                ('access_key', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Access Key')),
                ('secret_key', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Secret Key')),
                ('psk_api_binhex', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='PSK API Binhex')),
                ('psk_admin_binhex', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='PSK Admin Binhex')),
                ('bucket', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Media Bucket')),
                ('klx_bucket', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='KLX Bucket')),
                ('resource_bucket', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Resource Bucket')),
                ('endpoint', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Endpoint')),
                ('region', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Region')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Libera Backend',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Libera Backends',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServerIPv4',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('ipv4_address', models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', unique=True, verbose_name='IPv4 Address')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServerIPv6',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('ipv6_address', models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv6', unique=True, verbose_name='IPv6 Address')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('hostname', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='Hostname')),
                ('country_code', models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Country Code')),
                ('last_successful_contact', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('libera_backend', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='libera_backend_relation', to='App_CDN.liberabackend')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServerIPv4Relation',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('ipv4_address', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='App_CDN.liberaserveripv4')),
                ('libera_server', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='App_CDN.liberaserver')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='liberaserver',
            name='ipv4_addresses',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='libera_server_ipv4_relation', through='App_CDN.LiberaServerIPv4Relation', to='App_CDN.liberaserveripv4'),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServerIPv6Relation',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('ipv6_address', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='App_CDN.liberaserveripv6')),
                ('libera_server', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='App_CDN.liberaserver')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='liberaserver',
            name='ipv6_addresses',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='libera_server_ipv6_relation', through='App_CDN.LiberaServerIPv6Relation', to='App_CDN.liberaserveripv6'),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiberaServerMetric',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('uptime_seconds', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Uptime')),
                ('load_average_percentage', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Load Average Percentage')),
                ('memory_usage_percentage', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Memory Usage')),
                ('client_connections', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Client Connections')),
                ('gateway_connections', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Gateway Connections')),
                ('bandwidth_utilization_mbits', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Bandwidth Utilization Mbit/s')),
                ('bandwidth_available_mbits', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Bandwidth Available Mbit/s')),
                ('bandwidth_utilization_percentage', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Bandwidth Utilization Percentage')),
                ('total_disk_size_bytes', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Total Disk Size Bytes')),
                ('free_disk_size_bytes', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Free Disk Size Bytes')),
                ('cache_disk_usage_bytes', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Cache Disk Usage Bytes')),
                ('cache_object_count', models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Cache Object Count')),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('libera_server', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='libera_server_relation', to='App_CDN.liberaserver')),
            ],
        ),
    ]

Did somebody else experienced a similar problem or can explain how to fix this?
This issue seems to occour here in Cockroach:
https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/pkg/sql/create_index.go#L337

CockraochDB which is basically Postgres - it most certainly is NOT! From here we have However, CockroachDB does not support some of the PostgreSQL features or behaves differently from PostgreSQL because not all features can be easily implemented in a distributed system. So, they are not the same...

Corrected to Postgre syntax

Your SQL is clearly trying to do something with operator classes that PG doesn't like. I don't think anyone can say more than that because you've chosen to keep the SQL involved a secret.

All modeling and SQL stuff has been attached accordingly.

Must be me, but I don't see any CREATE TABLE or CREATE INDEX statement.

I fixed the issue, very essential thing i forgot about, simply install django-cockroachdb==5.0 ... Next just set DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_cockroachdb'

I fixed the issue, very essential thing I forgot about, simply install django-cockroachdb==5.0 ... Next, just set DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_cockroachdb'
This was just a small detail I stumbled on reading the cockroachdb docs again ... But really in the first instances it sounded to me like I would just need psycopg2 ...
